# Why scanf doesn't ask every turn

Tags: c, scanf

Explain me please why scanf doesn't ask Name 3 times?
How to change code to achieve it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int i=0;
    while ( i < 3 ) {
        char name[10];
        printf("Enter your name: ");
        scanf("%[^\n]", name);

        printf("Name: %s \n",name);
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

```
./a.out
Enter your name: D
Name: D 
Enter your name: Name: D 
Enter your name: Name: D
```

Comment: What made you make that complicated `[^\n]` matching? Add a space first and it'll probably be ok, but for real, use `fgets` when you want to read a line instead.

Comment: After the first entry, the newline is left in the buffer.  The next `scanf()` finds a newline, which is not valid, so it returns 0 instead of 1 as it did the first time.  Pay attention to the return value from `scanf()`.  Don't use `scanf()` to read lines of input.

Comment: Please change `scanf("%[^\n]", name);` to `scanf(" %[^\n]", name);` to eat the previous newline. Note the added space. It's worth spending an hour or two with a small program using `scanf()` and the man pages, exploring how the different rules work for the format specifiers, and how whitespace is handled in the input and in the format string itself. It is not simple. It varies with the format specifier.

Comment: The space before %c doesn't help. If user enters two chars, the second remains in buffer. % ./a.out
Enter your name: Dd
Name: D
Enter your name: Name: d
Enter your name: D
Name: D
Found another decision. Make a getchar(); after scanf to clear a buffer.

Comment: The space before %c still needed. I don't understand sense.
And there is one problem with that - you can't receive space as user input.